# Angular Karma tests configureTestingModule includes policy

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have this test working as expected, and everything is fine:

```
describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  }));

  it('should create footer component', (() => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

But the thing is that I notice that most of examples that I see over there, never imports the hole application module. So I decided to investigate a little bit more, and made some changes to:

```
describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [
        FooterComponent
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  }));

  it('should create footer component', (() => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

You can see the entire project [here](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular4-example-app/blob/master/src/app/core/footer/footer.component.spec.ts).

Which is a better solution? why? what are the best practices about this?

Should I import all modules one by one or only AppModule...?

Comment: So you probably don't want to here it from me, because i told you already in the other question :) But anyway: The target with unit tests is to test the smallest piece of code you have independently. You want to test the smallest possible unit. Because since you're developing module based you want modules to be independent too and not just to work only in your context. Another reason is that the tests load faster, the more redundant modules you add the more has to be loaded every time you execute a test and last but not least overall maintainability. Modules can change.

Comment: This probably belongs in [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I finally did this: https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular4-example-app/commit/943d797bb7bba35090d8cb322a878fb947525733